# NStimer value Reset problem

Tags: iphone, nstimer

In My application

1. I m starting one Nstimer when we log in.( loginViewController.m)
2. In my logout page( LogoutViewController.m) i want to stop the NSTimer.

   I have Creaated one Function ( loginViewController.m)

   ```
    -(void)InvalidateTimer
    {
       if ([self.timerDownload isValid]) 
       {
           [timerDownload invalidate];
           timerDownload = nil;
       }
     }
   ```

   And Call From LogoutViewController.m

   ```
   LoginViewController *login =[[LoginViewController alloc]init];

   [login InvalidateTimer];
   ```

   when we click Logout button.

   But self.timerDownload value is Coming 0X0 and not Inavlidate NSTimer.
   Please help

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You are creating new instance of login view controller and invalidating its timer. Ofcourse this new instance is not same as the old instance of login view controller where you started your timer.

Comment: How it is possible ?if i want

Comment: Use Notifications or Delegates.

Answer (score 0):

you have to make it as global in appdelegate or you have to send object of loginview to logout view and make it to work...